# Greater than string comparison in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

How do I express the following logic in a Makefile?

```
if $(XORG_VERSION) > "7.7"
   <do some thing>
fi
```

[Conditional Parts of Makefiles](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) only provides ifeq or ifneq.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not restricted to using the `make` conditional statements - each command is a shell command which may be as complex as you need (including a shell conditional statement):

Consider the following `makefile`:

```
dummy:
    if [ ${xyz} -gt 8 ] ; then \
        echo urk!! ${xyz} ;\
    fi
```

When you use `xyz=7 make --silent`, there is no output. When you use `xyz=9 make --silent`, it outputs `urk!! 9` as expected.

Comment: just curious, then why they make the conditional ifdef, etc?

Comment: `Make` doesn't (and probably shouldn't) assume anything about the underlying shell. For example, if you're running it under Windows, it may only have `cmd.exe` which isn't as powerful as `bash`. The real question would be why didn't gnu make provide more powerful comparison operators? To which my answer is "I have no idea" :-)

Comment: There are two distinct contexts in GNU make systems for conditionals - the **make conditionals** in the make file language itself evaluated at **parse-time** - they "control what make actually 'sees' in the makefile" which "cannot be used to control recipes at the time of execution" (see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals). And then there are **recipe conditionals** which are evaluated at **recipe-execution-time** and offer all the power of bash-like scripting

Answer (score 20):

I use the [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-sort) function to compare values lexicographically. The idea is, sort the list of two values, `$(XORG_VERSION)` and `7.7`, then take the first value - if it's `7.7` then the version is the same or greater.

```
ifeq "7.7" "$(word 1, $(sort 7.7 $(XORG_VERSION)))"
   <do some thing>
endif
```

Adjust `7.7` to `7.8` if you need the strict greater-than condition.

This approach improves portability by avoiding shell scripts and concomitant assumptions about the capabilities of the available OS shell.  However, it fails if the lexicographic ordering is not equivalent to the numerical ordering, for example when comparing `7.7` and `7.11`.

Comment: +1 Really clever way of doing the comparison without having to resort to using a shell command.

Comment: I've been using this formula for a few years and it just bit me... they have to be the same length. My situation is saying that "1048576" is less than "2047", which is true as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Using shell commands, as mentioned in the other answers, should suffice for most use cases:

```
if [ 1 -gt 0 ]; then \
    #do something \
fi
```

However, if you, like me, want to use *greater-than* comparison in order to ***then*** set a `make` variable via `make`'s `$(eval)` command, then you will find that attempting to do so using the other answer's model:

```
if [ 1 -gt 0 ]; then \
    $(eval FOO := value) \
fi
```

raises an error:

````
if [ 1 -gt 0 ]; then  fi;
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `if [ 1 -gt 0 ]; then  fi;'
make: *** [clean] Error 2```
````

I found a way how to sort out that problem and posted it [as a solution to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44288938/6314615). I hope someone finds it helpful!