# Performing greater-than less-than calculations in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to do this in a Makefile:

```
value = 2.0

if ${greaterthan ${value}, 1.50}
-> execute a rule
elseif ${lessthan ${value}, 0.50}
-> execute a rule
endif
```

It seems like quite a common thing to want to do. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Greater than string comparison in a Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437160/greater-than-string-comparison-in-a-makefile)*.

Comment: From the title of the question, it is not clear whether you want to do the if clause with **Makefile language** or with the **underlying shell** make is using (i.e. with `$(shell)` directives or in the recipes) such as the selected answer proposes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437160/string-comparation-in-makefileE), but basically you can use shell commands inside a Makefile. So the following is perfectly legal:

```
foo:
    if [ ${value} -gt 2 ] ; then \
         #Do stuff;\
    fi
```

Edit for a small disclaimer: IIRC, `bash` doesn't understand floating point arithmetic. It can interpret them as *strings*, but it might make things a little weird. Make sure you take this into consideration.

Comment: Would that work on Windows? And/or in [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)?

Comment: `sh` is the default shell used in GNU Makefile, I believe. If you are not using GNU Makefile then you would want to consult your Makefile version documentation to find out  what shell is being used. Or, you can just put a declaration such as `SHELL:=/bin/bash` at the top of your Makefile to declare it to use e.g. `bash`. Note that this can have some subtle effects on how the environment is passed between Makefile commands.

Comment: @PeterMortensen It won't work on "raw" Windows, such as a rule with `ls`, or a shell directive `$(shell ls)`.
GNU make (as of 3.81) on windows always selects `SHELL=sh.exe` from my experience, and it understands Windows batch only.
I don't know if this "shell" can then understand bash if you have Cygwin or MinGW installed.

Comment: This might work in rules, but it won't work in setup (for instance, to set compiler flags).

Answer (score 28):

Try this

In this example VER is checked for greater than 4

```
ifeq ($(shell test $(VER) -gt 4; echo $$?),0)
  IFLAGS += -I$(TOPDIR)/include
  LIBS += -L$(TOPDIR)/libs -lpcap
endif
```

Comment: What is implied here? [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)? Only works on Linux (and [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X))?

Comment: this is actually `sh` but it will work in `bash` as well

Answer (score 13):

My preferred way to do this is:

```
value = 2.0
ifeq ($(shell expr $(value) \>= 1.5), 1)
   # execute a rule
else ifeq ($(shell expr $(value) \<= 0.5), 1)
   # execute a rule
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Using shell commands, as mentioned in the other answers, should suffice for most use cases:

```
if [ 1 -gt 0 ]; then \
    #do something \
fi
```

However, if you, like me, want to use *greater-than* comparison in order to ***then*** set a `make` variable via `make`'s `$(eval)` command, then you will find that attempting to do so using the other answer's model:

```
if [ 1 -gt 0 ]; then \
    $(eval FOO := value) \
fi
```

raises an error:

````
if [ 1 -gt 0 ]; then  fi;
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `if [ 1 -gt 0 ]; then  fi;'
make: *** [clean] Error 2```
````

The reason is that [`make`'s `$(eval)` expression returns the empty string.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) The resulting bash code is then malformed.**

I came up with the following solution (after trying many different approaches!).

```
$(if $(shell [ $(FOO) -ge 1 ] && echo "OK"), \
    $(eval BAR := true), \
    $(eval BAR := false))
```

It is necessary to print out a string after performing the arithmetic comparison (the `echo "OK"` part) because `make`'s `$(if)` operator its based on empty-string logic:

> *$(if condition,then-part[,else-part])*
>
> The if function provides support for conditional expansion in a functional context (as opposed to the GNU make makefile conditionals such as ifeq (see Syntax of Conditionals).
>
> The first argument, condition, first has all preceding and trailing whitespace stripped, then is expanded. If it expands to any non-empty string, then the condition is considered to be true. If it expands to an empty string, the condition is considered to be false.

Source: [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions)

Hope this helps!

** **Note**: Initially, I thought that that issue could be easily fixed by adding a bash command that doesn't do anything to the expression, such as `true`:

```
if [ $(VALUE) -ge 1 ]; then \
    true; $(eval BAR := GreaterOrEqualThan1) \
else \
    true; $(eval BAR := LowerThan1) \
fi
```

That turned out to be a terrible idea. I still haven't figured out why, but the `else` branch is always executed, independently of the result of the comparison.

I think I should open a question for this case.

Comment: That is because the `$(eval BAR := XXX)` is a **makefile** construct evaluated at makefile-parsing time, while the shell recipe that tests the condition is a **shell-like recipe* evaluated at recipe execution time.