# Great than, less than condition in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have time1 variable in makefile which takes different integers. I need to check it in some range , and need to write condition like this if (time1 >= range1 || time1 <= range2) echo passed or echo failed.

I read GNU make manual, but didn`t find an answer. How can I write condition ???

Comment: Are you using parentheses or square brackets? These commands are executed by your shell, most probably bash. Check the documentation (https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performing greater-than less-than calculations in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442304/performing-greater-than-less-than-calculations-in-a-makefile)

Comment: No, its doesn`t solve my problem, I get an syntax error, that require "then" from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the shell, but you can do it also in make. Coincidentally, the [GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) has integer arithmetic and comparison:

```
include gmtt.mk

$(if $(or $(call int-ge,$(TIME1),$(RANGE1)),$(call int-le,$(TIME1),$(RANGE2))),passed,failed)
```