# Complex conditions check in Makefile

Tags: makefile

In my Makefile I would like to check the following complex condition:

```
ifdef VAR1 || VAR2 || VAR3
action
endif
```

however the documentation says the syntax like that is not supported. So the only simple workaround that came to my mind is to use the concatenation:

```
ifneq ($(VAR1)$(VAR2)$(VAR3),)
action
endif
```

Are there any other more correct solutions?

For the following case:

```
ifdef VAR1 && VAR2 && VAR3
action
endif
```

one need to write

```
ifdef VAR1
ifdef VAR2
ifdef VAR3
action
endif
endif
endif
```

which is also ugly. Are there more elegant alternatives?

Comment: Related (not duplicate): *[Greater than string comparison in a Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437160)*

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If your `make` is GNU-make and all the defined variables include a non-space
character,

```
ifdef VAR1 && VAR2 && VAR3
```

can be written as

```
ifneq ($(and $(VAR1),$(VAR2),$(VAR3)),)
```

On a related note, probably [and](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html#Conditional-Functions) function requires version 3.81 or later.

In case some defined variables may be empty strings,
if we prepare the following functions:

```
ifndef_any_of = $(filter undefined,$(foreach v,$(1),$(origin $(v))))
ifdef_any_of = $(filter-out undefined,$(foreach v,$(1),$(origin $(v))))
```

then the following conditions:

```
ifdef VAR1 || VAR2
ifdef VAR1 && VAR2
```

can be written respectively using [call](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html#Call-Function) function:

```
ifneq ($(call ifdef_any_of,VAR1 VAR2),)
ifeq ($(call ifndef_any_of,VAR1 VAR2),)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! New for me to learn about `$(or ...)` plus `$(and ...)`.

Comment: @dma_k: Sorry, probably the previous answer was a little lengthy. I edited the answer.

Comment: can you explain the `foreach v` part?

Comment: And how do I add multiple selections if the syntax is like `ifeq ($(VAR1),some-string)` combined with `ifeq ($(VAR2),some-other-string)`

Comment: @rubo77: For `foreach` function, [this document](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html#Foreach-Function) will help. `v` is an arbitrary name. It can be `w` or `x` or whatever, as long as it matches the name in `origin $(v)`.

Comment: @rubo77: As for your second comment, I cannot think of concise answer now, sorry. Probably that problem will be worth posting as another question.

Comment: [combine-multiple-ifeq-and-ifneq-in-a-gnu-makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517970/)