# How to check if a variable is equal to one of two values using the if/or/and functions

Tags: gnu-make

In a GNU makefile, I would like to set an output variable to one value (let's say "true") if an input variable is equal to one of two values and to another value ("false") when it is not.

Thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584872/complex-conditions-check-in-makefile/5586785#5586785) I've learned about the `and` and the `or` functions and soon after that I have found the `if` function. These functions seem to be available in my version of make, so I would like to use them. I would like to write something like that:

```
TEST_INPUT = `hostname`
TEST_OUTPUT = $(if $(or $(eq $(TEST_INPUT),hal9000),
                        $(eq $(TEST_INPUT),pipboy)),true,false)
```

Unfortunately I can't, because I couldn't find any obvious form of the expected `eq` function. I am able to achieve what I want using the `filter` function:

```
TRUE_HOSTS = hal9000 pipboy
TEST_OUTPUT = $(if $(filter $(TEST_INPUT),$(TRUE_HOSTS)),true,false)
```

or the `subst` function:

```
TEST_OUTPUT = $(if $(and $(subst hal9000,,$(TEST_INPUT)),
                         $(subst pipboy,,$(TEST_INPUT))),
                   false,true)
```

but for me it isn't a nice looking nor readable code. Are there solutions closer to the first example (the one using not existing `eq` function)? Maybe I don't catch the purpose of the `if`, `and` and `or` functions at all?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The thing that is odd about GNUmake conditionals is that there is no boolean type in make -- everything is a string.  So the conditionals all work with the empty string for 'false' and all non-empty strings (including strings like `false` and `0`) as being 'true'.

That being said, the fact that `eq` is missing is an annoyonace albeit a minor one.  Generally you can get what you want from `filter` or `findstring`, and `filter` often allows you to search a whole list of strings to match as in your second example.

If you really need it, you can define your own eq function:

```
eq = $(and $(findstring $(1),$(2)),$(findstring $(2),$(1)))
```

Which you unfortunately have to use as `$(call eq,`...`,`...`)`

Comment: Thanks for confirming my feeling that comparison functions are not provided. Your `eq` function is also pretty smart and more readable than my solutions (I will shamelessly use it). Thanks :)

Comment: I'm using it to, though I reserve the right to feel some shame about it.

Answer (score 13):

Chris Dodd's answer is good, but there is a corner case for which it provides an incorrect result. If both of the variables being compared are empty (i.e. false) then it will return false. An improved version would be:

```
eq = $(if $(or $(1),$(2)),$(and $(findstring $(1),$(2)),\
                                $(findstring $(2),$(1))),1)
```

This first checks to see either of the arguments are non-empty, and if so uses the previous technique to compare them. Otherwise it returns 1, to indicate that the values are equal as they are both empty.

Comment: Or you could avoid that case `eq = $(and $(findstring x$(1),x$(2)), $(findstring x$(2),x$(1)))`.

Comment: @akim took me a while to find the trick (prepending the strings with `x` -- could be any character really). Good one!

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your context, consider using the GMSL (GNU Make Standard Library), which is a collection of functions in a make include file "...that provide list and string manipulation, integer arithmetic, associative arrays, stacks, and debugging facilities." See http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/

It has a "string equal" function, seq, as well as a number of other useful manipulators:

```
    TEST_INPUT = $(shell hostname -s)
    TEST_OUTPUT = $(if $(or $(call seq,$(TEST_INPUT),hal9000),
                            $(call seq,$(TEST_INPUT),pipboy)),true,false)
```

Also, use the $(shell ...) syntax instead of backticks for better handling of newlines.