# Is there a logical OR operator for the 'ifneq'?

Tags: makefile

Is there a logical OR operator for the 'ifneq ... endif' statement?

That is, I'd not like to execute some statements if variable 'var1' or 'var2' is defined. Something like this:

```
ifneq ($(WNDAP660),y) OR $(WNADAP620),y))
...
endif
```

I've tried ifneq `($(WNDAP660),$(filter $(WNADAP620),y y))`, but it is not working.

Comment: You probably want an AND rather than an OR, don't you?  If you wrote `y != WNDAP660 || y != WNADAP620`, then at least one and possibly both alternatives will be true, so the action will always be taken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefile ifeq logical or](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656425/makefile-ifeq-logical-or)

Comment: Older duplicate: *[Complex conditions check in Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584872/complex-conditions-check-in-makefile)*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one:

```
ifeq ($(filter y,$(WNDAP660) $(WNADAP620)),)
...
endif
```

Comment: Can you explain me this?? suppose I want ifeq ($(WNDAP660),y) OR $(WNADAP620),y)) then what should I do?

Comment: Just negate the conditional: `ifneq ($(filter y,$(WNDAP660) $(WNADAP620)),)`

Comment: If any of your variables is set to '`y`', then `filter` returns them, say <nothing> if none of them is set, '`y`' for a single set variable, '`y y`' for case when both of them are set.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a logical OR operator for the 'ifneq'

NO. Posix Make is anemic. There's no logical OR for any of them. See, for example, [Logical AND, OR, XOR operators inside ifeq ... endif construct condition](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2005-10/msg00056.html) on the GNU make mailing list. They have been requested for decades (literally).

Posix make is nearly useless, and one of the first things you usually do on a BSD system is install the GNU Make (gmake) port so you can compile libraries and programs.

If you are using GNU Make, then you have other options.

One alternative is to use shell math to simulate a circuit. For example, the following is from [Crypto++'s](http://www.cryptopp.com/) [GNUmakefile](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile):

```make
IS_DARWIN = $(shell uname -s | $(EGREP) -i -c "darwin")
GCC42_OR_LATER = $(shell $(CXX) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -i -c "^gcc version (4\.[2-9]|[5-9])")
CLANG_COMPILER = $(shell $(CXX) --version 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -i -c "clang")

# Below, we are building a boolean circuit that says "Darwin && (GCC 4.2 || Clang)"
MULTIARCH_SUPPORT = $(shell echo $$(($(IS_DARWIN) * ($(GCC42_OR_LATER) + $(CLANG_COMPILER)))))
ifneq ($(MULTIARCH_SUPPORT),0)
  CXXFLAGS += -arch x86_64 -arch i386
else
  CXXFLAGS += -march=native
endif
```

When building such a circuit, use `-c` for `grep` and `egrep` to count hits. Then use `non-0` and `0` values. That's in case something has a value of, say, `2`. That's why the test above is `ifneq ($(MULTIARCH_SUPPORT),0)` (*if not equal to 0*).

Another alternative is to use [GNU Make Standard Library](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/). It adds the following operators: not, and, or, xor, nand, nor, xnor to the CVS version.

Answer (score 3):

Crude but effective:

```
ifneq ($(WNDAP660),y) 
 ifneq ($(WNADAP620),y)
 ...
 endif
endif
```

Answer (score -2):

I've test the following code, which works well

```
ifeq ($(var1),value1) or ($(var2), value2)
   #do something here
endif
```

Comment: ignores the second condition in my GNU make 4.1 on Fedora