# combine multiple ifeq and ifneq in a gnu Makefile

Tags: makefile

How do I add multiple selections if the syntax is like

```
ifeq ($(VAR1),some-string)
```

combined with

```
ifneq ($(VAR2),some-other-string)
```

combined with some more...

Is there a one liner? Like (fantasycode):

```
ifeq $VAR1=some-string and not $VAR2=some-other-string
```

i found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584872/complex-conditions-check-in-makefile) which is not clear to me becauser there is no equation in the ifeq statement there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no `and` operator for the conditionals (but there is a `and` function that can be used in conditionals). The `if`, `and` and `or` conditional functions consider that the empty string is false and that anything else is true (including strings containing only spaces). The first proposal in the answer you found tests whether variables are the empty string or not. The second tests whether variables are defined or not. In both cases it does not test whether their value is equal to a reference string. This may be the reason why it was not immediately clear to you.

In your (simple) case you can nest the conditionals:

```
ifeq ($(VAR1),some-string)
  ifneq ($(VAR2),some-other-string)
<do something>
  endif
endif
```

`<do something>` will be considered if and only if the two conditionals pass.

For complex situations with many conditions you can compute individual matching variables:

```
MATCH1 := $(if $(strip $(VAR1)),$(patsubst some-string,,$(VAR1)),NO)
```

Variable `MATCH1` will take value:

- `NO` if `VAR1` is undefined, is the empty string or a string of spaces,
- empty string if it is equal to `some-string`,
- else the value of `VAR1`.

So, it will be the empty string if and only if `VAR1 == some-string`. Same for `NOMATCH1`:

```
MOMATCH1 := $(if $(strip $(VAR2)),$(patsubst some-other-string,,$(VAR2)),NO)
```

`NOMATCH1` will be non empty if and only if `VAR2 != some-other-string`.

Now, your main condition can be expressed using conditional functions:

```
ifeq ($(or $(MATCH1),$(MATCH2),...),)
  ifneq ($(and $(NOMATCH1),$(NOMATCH2),...),)
<do something>
  endif
endif
```

Comment: You can indent but to avoid problems use spaces, not tabs. Tabs are interpreted by make as the leading character of a recipe line.

Comment: so here in my Makefile I could indend the ifeq with spaces only? https://github.com/freifunk-kiel/site-ffki/blob/nightly/site.mk#L84 , In the later content of that Makefile, I have indented with tabs also, is that a problem? and why not, if not? maybe you can start a PR on my Makefile to add indentions correctly? :)

Comment: Sorry, my comment was not clear enough: you can indent the conditionals themselves with tabs, if you wish but be careful with the innermost make statements in this nest of conditionals. Indenting them with tabs may lead to unexpected results (errors). In the case you have on GitHub, the statements are only variable assignments, not make rules. It should be OK even if indented with tabs.

Comment: @rubo77: I just had a better look at your GitHub repository. Be careful, line 86 (`GLUON_SITE_PACKAGES += -ffffm-button-bind`) of your `site.mk` Makefile will never be used by make because the two nested conditionals it is enclosed in are exclusive one from the other... Probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. How could I put my two lies in one? Couldn't I just use shell campaign in$() somehow?

Comment: @rubo77: I would probably code this differently: `GLUON_SITE_PACKAGES-x86-generic := -ffffm-button-bind`,  `GLUON_SITE_PACKAGES-x86-64 := -ffffm-button-bind`, ... And then: `GLUON_SITE_PACKAGES += $(GLUON_SITE_PACKAGES-$(GLUON_TARGET))`. No conditionals at all, just make variables. Would it help?

Comment: Great! +1 I will try that

Answer (score 0):

```
# Param 1 : Thing to do
# Param 2: VAR VALUE VAR1 VALUE1 VAR2 VALUE2 ...
# Each param VAR/VALUE must be space separated
define rec_check
    $(if $(strip $(2)),$(if $(findstring _$($(word 1,$(2)))_,_$(word 2,$(2))_),$(call rec_check,$(1),$(subst $(word 1,$(2)) $(word 2,$(2)),,$(2)))),$(1))
endef

# Usage :
# MY_VAR=ok
# MY_VAR2=ok
# $(call rec_check,echo "It works",MY_VAR ok MY_VAR2 ok)
# $(call rec_check,echo "It does not work",MY_VAR ok MY_VAR2 ok2)
```

It is limited to values without any space though, but it works. Also, it only checks AND conditions.

You still can improve to your need